# Reading SendGird WebHook response

Tags: c#, .net, api, webhooks, sendgrid

Can any one help me on how to read the response from Event Web Hook

"SendGrid's Event Webhook will notify a URL of your choice via
HTTP POST with information about events that occur as SendGrid processes your email"
This is what mentioned on site.

below is my api

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("webhook")]
  public void EmailEvents([FromBody]SendGridEventObject[] eventList)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = System.IO.File.CreateText(@"D:\EmailResponseStatus.txt"))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    if (eventList != null && eventList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var evnt in eventList)
                        {
                            serializer.Serialize(file, evnt);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(file, "empty");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I have given this url on sendgrid and try to run integration test it says
A sample event notification will be sent to your endpoint shortly,
but i dont see anything happening,when i have set debug point as well.

When i use the url as they have mentioned in below link
https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/

i can see the response, can any one tell me what i am doing wrong here in my Api endpoint ?
i want this response to be read and send it to other service.

Really Appreciate your help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same thing happen to me, did you solve it?